# How to sign a pdf digitally by using mupdf(ios)

Tags: ios, pdf, digital-signature, mupdf

I have successfully integrated mupdf into my project. now i can able to browse pdf, add new annotations and editing but i didn't know how to embed digital signature into pdf.

Can any one suggest me the steps for embedding digital signature into pdf.